# How to make redirects when visitors click from search engines ONLY?

Tags: search, redirect, web

How to make redirects when visitors click from search engines ONLY?

If visit by typing website url. It will not redirects to any websites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

analyze Referer string, when session just start